# How to Replace elements in a nested list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, nested-lists

I am trying to have a list like this...

`'((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 4 7) (2 5 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6))`

and replace all occurrences of a certain number.

For example when running

`(replace 4 "x" '((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 4 7) (2 5 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6)))`

The Desired output is

`'((0 1 2) (3 x 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 x 7) (2 5 8) (0 x 8) (2 x 6)))`

What I have tried so far is

`(define (replace var player list)
  (if (null? list)
      '()
      (if (list? (car list))
          (replace var player (cdr list))
          (if (equal? var (car list))
              (cons player (replace var player (cdr list)))
              (cons (car list) (replace var player (cdr list)))
          ))))`

Which when I run to replace all 1's with an x the output is `'(0 "x" 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, you are only missing actually applying the function on `(car lst)` whenever the first element is a list itself, ie:

```
...
(if (list? (car list))
      (cons (replace var player (car list))         ;; missing this
            (replace var player (cdr list)))
      (if ...
```

Also, avoid using built-in procedures as variable names (eg. [`list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%29%29)), and when using conditionals, instead of nesting multiple `if` statements, use [`cond`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) or its relatives that better translate to the conventional `if ... else if ... else ...` idea.